# spotify installed, run error

Tags: 12.10, spotify

Terminal says:

```
(spotify:20514): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_box_pack: assertion `GTK_IS_BOX (box)' failed
22:11:19.149 I [ap_connection.cpp:1767          ] Connecting to AP fonda.lon.spotify.com:4070
22:11:19.155 I [AppRunner.cpp:55                ] onboarding-popup: not installed
22:11:19.155 I [AppRunner.cpp:252               ] onboarding-popup: installing app
22:11:19.155 I [AppRunner.cpp:273               ] onboarding-popup (version 0.0.0): metadata query started
22:11:19.156 I [AppManager.cpp:206              ] Creating instance of the application install.

(spotify:20514): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid cast from `GtkFixed' to `GtkBox'

(spotify:20514): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_box_pack: assertion `GTK_IS_BOX (box)' failed
22:11:19.173 I [ap_connection.cpp:1234          ] Connected to AP: 78.31.8.102:4070
22:11:19.499 I [AppRunner.cpp:273               ] onboarding-popup (version 0.0.0): metadata query complete
22:11:19.499 I [AppRunner.cpp:273               ] onboarding-popup (version 0.0.0): download started
22:11:19.526 I [MainView.cpp:7250               ] Load complete (0) url: sp://faa645cea6e98f854b789c7a6f4beeef6d3ca53c.home/index.html
22:11:19.604 I [upnp.cpp:508                    ] 192.168.1.1: got external ip 0xD56A4C28
22:11:19.646 E [file_system_monitor_linux.cpp:500] FileSystemMonitorLinux() failed [inotify_init()]
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

What's wrong ?

Ubuntu 12.10 32bit.

Spotify installed without any problems, when I try to run spotify, problem starts.

Answer (score 1):

People with the same problem say that it went away with an updgrade to kernel  linux-image-3.5.0-23-generic.

Before that they solved it by raising the number of max_user_instances, by running:

```
sudo echo 8192 > /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_instances
```

(Taken from: [Spotify wont start: FileSystemMonitorLinux() failed](http://community.spotify.com/t5/Desktop-Linux/Spotify-wont-start-FileSystemMonitorLinux-failed/td-p/243130/page/2))

This seems to make sense since the error message you got showed `failed [inotify_init()]`. The man page for `inotify_init` shows several possible errors, including

```
The user limit on the total number of inotify instances has been reached.
```

and

```
The system limit on the total number of file descriptors has been reached.
```